# ASP.net ASCX and ASPX transfering data from one to the other

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this page, shown below. In the ASCX file, the data is generated using a DataGrid in which a user searches for fields and it displays results based on input criteria. This is using a stored procedure and parameters to perform this search. It then returns the results, populates a datagrid, now my question is how would I go about in my ASPX page having my disk icon allow a user to download a CSV of the data that has been returned in the ASCX page. I obviously need to run a command to generate the CSV file from the database, which I have all the code for, but my question really is how do I know what the user has searched for, or what results were returned I guess best put. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to expose the search criteria via a public function.

So add to the ascx;

```
Public String GetSearchCriteria() {
    //Code to return the search criteria here
}
```

On the aspx in the button click event;

```
String = myControl.GetSearchCriteria();
//Call database and get data for CSV
```

Or you could pass the data back to the aspx.  Same method;

ascx;

```
Public List<MyData> GetData() {
    //Code to return the data here
}
```

On the aspx in the button click event;

```
List<MyData> myData = myControl.GetData();
//Produce CSV from data.
```

Different ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

Does the ASCX take care of all of the database interaction?

If so, wouldn't it encapsulate the export to CSV functionality inside of itself, with no need to talk to its parent container? If so, wouldn't you just expose a method from the user control that the parent can call into?

Comment: Yes the ASCX handles everything, the ASPX just combines several ASCX files and provides some styling to make it look nice. How do I go about exposing the method on the user control so that aspx can call to it?

Comment: 1) Add a new public function to the user control then 2) set the onclick for the icon to call this.usercontrol.exportfunc().

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the page where the control resides via the Page property. Something like this could work (in a control's event):

```
MyPage parent = (MyPage) this.Page;
parent.SetDownloadUrl(myDownloadUrl);
```

where `MyPage` is the type of your page, and SetDownloadUrl sets whatever properties you need in order to display the download link.

---

Also, the reverse is possible. If the download link is kept in a controls property, you could use:

```
MyControl control = (MyControl) FindControl("myControlName");
ImageDownload.NavigateUrl = control.DownloadUrl;
```

where `MyControl` is the type of the control, and it has a `DownloadUrl` property that has been set.